# Deploying codefirst is not creating all table fields

Tags: entity-framework, c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4, ef-code-first

Im having some issues trying to deploy a code first based mvc4 application to azure.

It works fine when creating a localdb however when trying to deploy to azure the UserProfile table only Username & UserId fields are created.

My model looks like

```
[Table("UserProfile")]
public class UserProfile
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    public Guid ConsumerId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public bool IsMale { get; set; }
    public string Mobile { get; set; }
    [DefaultValue(false)]
    public bool IsSmsVerified { get; set; }
    public string SmsVerificationCode { get; set; }

}
```

Context

```
  public class UsersContext : DbContext
{
    public UsersContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<UserProfile> UserProfiles { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ExternalUserInformation> ExternalUsers { get; set; }
}
```

Configuration

```
 internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<Web.Models.UsersContext>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
    }

    protected override void Seed(Web.Models.UsersContext context)
    {
        //  This method will be called after migrating to the latest version.

        //  You can use the DbSet<T>.AddOrUpdate() helper extension method 
        //  to avoid creating duplicate seed data. E.g.
        //
        //    context.People.AddOrUpdate(
        //      p => p.FullName,
        //      new Person { FullName = "Andrew Peters" },
        //      new Person { FullName = "Brice Lambson" },
        //      new Person { FullName = "Rowan Miller" }
        //    );
        //

        WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("DefaultConnection", "UserProfile", "UserId", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);
```

Is there a magic switch somewhere that I need to turn on?

Comment: What database initialization strategy are you using? I'm thinking that you might have it set to something like `CreateDatabaseIfNotExists` or something equivalent.

Comment: Can you show your DataContext class?

Comment: hi Richard the database is created in azure its just missing some of the fields. @hbrock I've updated my post

Comment: @DiverDan, have you looked at this link: https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/tutorials/web-site-with-sql-database/#bkmk_deploytowindowsazure1

Comment: @DiverDan ~ yeap. Could you check what your database initialization strat is? Because if it's something like `CreateDatabaseIfNotExists`, then it's definitely going to be created the first time, but it won't be updated if your model changes somehow (which could account for the missing fields).

Comment: @hbrock was on the right track. It was creating the 2nd connection string that fixed my problem. Kind of cryptic way to get it working......https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/tutorials/web-site-with-sql-database/#header-14

Comment: the new connection string, is again a once off solution most likely.